# Will $(document).ready(function(){ ... }) clean all previous event handlers registered with document ready?

Tags: jquery, handler, jquery-events

I have a doubt about the `.ready()` function in jQuery. In particular, consider a situation where someone has bound some handler to the document ready event, and I execute

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* my code here */ })
```

Will this overwrite the previously registered handler, or only add a new one (mine) to the event?

Comment: This is something that you could have easily figured out by yourself: `$( func1 ); $( func2 );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed. You can use that function as many times as you like. Here's the JQuery documentation.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$(document).ready()

All the functions, $(document).ready(), $(window).load() along with binds like click all get added to the stack. This way you can use the $(document).ready on all your javaascript files.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: it is added to the set of event handlers for this event. It is also easy to test:

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert('test1');});
$(document).ready(function(){alert('test2');});
```

Answer (score 2):

It will add your new event handler to the existing handlers if those handlers were also added with jQuery.ready. If they were added directly via DOM, they will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

No, it adds your handler to the set.

Answer (score 0):

It will push to the stack, so no it won't override.

Answer (score 0):

As with all event handlers that you bind via jQuery, it will be added to a queue of event handler for the element/event.

jQuery has the `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to stop the execution of event handler attached to the same element: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Answer (score 0):

This will add the new function to the handler stack. Furthermore, if it is run after the DOM has been initialized, the function will be executed instantly.